# Output of the SQLite's foreign_key_list pragma

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, pragma

Using **SQLite3** with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Company TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, Country TEXT NOT NULL, City TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Orders(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT);
```

and issuing this command:

```
PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Orders);
```

results in the following output:

```
0|0|Customers|CustomerID|ID|RESTRICT|RESTRICT|NONE
```

As the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list) says nothing about the meaning of the output of this pragma, apart from the obvious (*Customers* - Parent table, *CustomerID* - Child key, *ID* - Parent key, *RESTRICT* - ON DELETE and the second *RESTRICT* - ON UPDATE) I presume that *NONE* coresponds to the unsupported MATCH clause.

The thing which I can't figure out by myself is the meaning of the first two zeros. Could someone tell me what it is?

Comment: First 2 are `id` and `seq`. `id` represents unique identifier for foreign key in a table. If there are multiple foreign key the `id` will be 0, 1, ...

Comment: `seq` is column sequence number for the key. It is used for muti column foreign key

Comment: @kuro Please write that as an answer.

Comment: Thank You for the information, @kuro! As CL said, add this as an answer so I can accept it. I would like to ask You to share (if possible) the source of this information. It would be helpful to know where one could read about this.

Comment: @scopchanov, added the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `PRAGMA foreign_key_list()` consists of following columns in order -

`id`, `seq`, `table`, `from`, `to`, `on_update`, `on_delete`, `match`

So, in the output you got the first two `0`s are for `id` and `seq`.

Take below example executed in sqlite3 cli with header and column option on -

```
CREATE TABLE Test (first INTEGER, second INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (first) REFERENCES A(a) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (second) REFERENCES B(x) ON DELETE CASCADE);
sqlite> 
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Test);
id          seq         table       from        to          on_update   on_delete   match     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           0           B           second      x           NO ACTION   CASCADE     NONE      
1           0           A           first       a           NO ACTION   CASCADE     NONE
```

I know the table `Test` look like a nightmare, but just ignore the horrible schema for a moment.

You can see there are two foreign keys in table `Test` and so there are two entries shown in `PRAGMA foreign_key_list()` output. You can see the `id` fields value are 0 and 1 respectively but the `seq` values are all 0.

As you may know sqlite allows multiple column names in foreign key statement.
So if you take the next example -

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Test2 (first INTEGER, second INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (first, second) REFERENCES A(a, b) ON DELETE CASCADE);
sqlite> 
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key_list(Test2);
id          seq         table       from        to          on_update   on_delete   match     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           0           A           first       a           NO ACTION   CASCADE     NONE      
0           1           A           second      b           NO ACTION   CASCADE     NONE
```

So, the multiple column key results in multiple rows in the output where `id` is same as this is actually one key. But the `seq` value differs as there are multiple columns in the key.

Comment: Perfect! Thank You once again!