# sqlite3 & python: get list of primary and foreign keys

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am very new to sql and intermediate at python. Using sqlite3, how can I get a print() list of of primary and foreign keys (per table) in my database?

Using Python2.7, SQLite3, PyCharm.

sqlite3.version = 2.6.0

sqlite3.sqlite_version = 3.8.11

Also note: when I set up the database, I enabled FKs as such:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
conn.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')
```

I tried the following:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(db_path)
print(conn.execute("PRAGMA table_info"))
print(conn.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_list"))
```

Which returned:

```
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002FCBDC0>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002FCBDC0>
```

I also tried the following, which prints nothing (but I think this may be because **it's a dummy database with tables and fields but no records**):

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(db_path)
rows = conn.execute('PRAGMA table_info')
for r in rows:
    print r
rows2 = conn.execute('PRAGMA foreign_key_list')
for r2 in rows2:
    print r2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unknown or malformed PRAGMA statements are ignored.

The problem with your PRAGMAs is that the table name is missing. You have to get a list of all tables, and then execute those PRAGMAs for each one:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'")
tables = [row[0] for row in rows]

def sql_identifier(s):
    return '"' + s.replace('"', '""') + '"'

for table in tables:
    print("table: " + table)
    rows = db.execute("PRAGMA table_info({})".format(sql_identifier(table)))
    print(rows.fetchall())
    rows = db.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_list({})".format(sql_identifier(table)))
    print(rows.fetchall())
```

Comment: thank you @CL.  in case anyone else has a related question, found a good supplement with explanation of PRAGMA foreign_key_list outputs:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424476/output-of-the-sqlites-foreign-key-list-pragma

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    sqlite_master 
WHERE 
    type ='table' AND 
name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%';
```

this sql will show all table in database, for eache table run sql `PRAGMA table_info(your_table_name);`, you can get the primary key of the table.

Those pictures show what sql result like in my database:
 [first sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uLcE.png)
[second sql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPfJ6.png)

Comment: is that python sqlite3 syntax?